# Scraping airbnb with python lxml

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to find a node on an airbnb listing. The node is

```
< div class="col-md-3 text-muted" data-reactid=".2e7if3twveo.0.0.0.0.1.6.0">< span data-reactid=".2e7if3twveo.0.0.0.0.1.6.0.0">The Space< /span> /div>
```

---

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

url ='https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/5711344'
tree = html.fromstring(br.open(url).get_data())
els = tree.xpath('//div[@class="row"]/div[@class="col-md-3 text-muted"]')
for element in els:
    if element.text.find('The Space') >= 0:
```

Somehow 'The Space' is not retrievable.

Comment: Is this a copy-paste error? `< /span> /div>` The `/div` doesn't have a closing `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me: I used BeautifulSoup to fetch the divs by their class attribute then looped for the correct one.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/5711344'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'col-md-3 text-muted'})
for div in divs:
    space = div.find('span').text.strip()
    if space == "The Space":
        print(space)
```